# Open file with external program from classpath (inside Jar)

Tags: java, swing, desktop, embedded-resource

I'm building a program where I need to open a simple .txt file with the Os's default text reader. I know you can do this with:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop = open(new File("filename"));
```

But this opens a file from the System's file path not the class path. Since my program will have to be distributed and passed around, the help file needs to stay within the .jar file.

I tried implementing it with `getClass().getResource("/resources/Help.txt")`

Like so:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop = open(new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/Help.txt")));
```

However, this does not work. I even tried:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop = open(new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Help.txt")));
```

But this does not work either.

The Help.txt file is already in the class path, I just need to figure out how to open this file using a external program, however, from within the class path. Is this possible? If yes, how? If not, is there an alternative way to implement this?

Comment: *"I just need to figure out how to open this file using a external program"*  Why 'external'?  If it is just a text file, I'd use a `JTextArea` to display it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would do that, but that would mean that I need to make a new JPanel and a new window entirely. This is a help button and I would rather have it open in a external application.

Comment: *"..but that would mean that I need to make a new JPanel and a new window entirely."* Wow! It would only require a handful of lines of code.  Less than what it would take to extract the resource to a file first. But use a non modal `JDialog` rather than a `JWindow` or `JFrame`..

Answer (score 1):

> ..is there an alternative way to implement this?

Extract the bytes out to a temporary file. Then use the Desktop API to display the temporary file.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Code implementation would be wonderful :)

Comment: *"Code implementation would be wonderful :)"*  Any signs of actual effort in achieving your goal using my advice would be wonderful. (SO is not a code generation service.)

Comment: Jeez. Sorry for asking for help. I'm a mere student in grade 11 who's been at this for 3 days. I think I've been putting in a lot more effort than you think I've been.

Comment: I have spent no time wondering how much time you spent on this.  It is your problem after all, not ours, not mine.  My point is that SO is not some help desk, it is not a place to find a tutor, and if you cannot make (and show) some progress towards achieving this goal of yours, then there is not point to bringing it to SO in efforts to get spoon fed solutions. BTW - *"in grade 11"* If that's the case then the class should have already covered everything you need to know to complete the task.  Go back and review your notes, and check that the app. is not trying to 'overstep' the requirement.